# Converting scrollview content to Bitmap Android

Tags: android

How to convert scrollview content to Bitmap.I follow bellow link but it gives Java.lang.IllegalargumwentException.Width and height must be >0.

[How to convert all content in a scrollview to a bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738448/how-to-convert-all-content-in-a-scrollview-to-a-bitmap/19383606#19383606)

Comment: well, it the scrollview width/height is = 0, this mean that you re trying to capture the scrollview to early. Try to listen to the view event or a global view listener so you know when your view is drawn totally and the good time to capture it.

Comment: As ScrollView contains only one child, so you can get context from that child instead of scrollview

Comment: Thank u Gresse.I will try