# view.getDrawingCache() is deprecated in Android API 28

Tags: android, bitmap, screenshot

In android API 28 `view.getDrawingCache()` has been deprecated. Is there any newer solution to generate a Bitmap of a particular view in android.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found a way to use PixelCopy API for retrieving the view as a Bitmap. Used Kotlin

```
fun getBitmapFromView(view: View, activity: Activity, callback: (Bitmap) -> Unit) {
    activity.window?.let { window ->
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val locationOfViewInWindow = IntArray(2)
        view.getLocationInWindow(locationOfViewInWindow)
        try {
            PixelCopy.request(window, Rect(locationOfViewInWindow[0], locationOfViewInWindow[1], locationOfViewInWindow[0] + view.width, locationOfViewInWindow[1] + view.height), bitmap, { copyResult ->
                if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                    callback(bitmap)
                }
                // possible to handle other result codes ...
            }, Handler())
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            // PixelCopy may throw IllegalArgumentException, make sure to handle it
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [ref](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy#request(android.view.Window,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.view.PixelCopy.OnPixelCopyFinishedListener,%20android.os.Handler))

Comment: Why does Google always have to complicate things? I want the bitmap the same time I'm calling the method not later on in the future using callbacks.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19383606/812919) today which I'm going to use instead.

Comment: `PixelCopy` requires API Level 26 and above. If you want compatability, for older API level, use the solution posted by @daka.

Comment: @daka you can use [link](https://github.com/Muddz/PixelShot) this library. It handles all stuffs for saving an image of a view.

Comment: A better and optimised solution would be "view.drawToBitmap()"

Answer (score 78):

**Two ways to get bitmap of view**

1. **Using Canvas**
2. **Using Pixel Api**

---

### **`Canvas Java`**

```
Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    );
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view,int defaultColor) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    );
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(defaultColor);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

### **`Canvas Kotlin`**

```
fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    view.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}

fun getBitmapFromView(view: View, defaultColor: Int): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    canvas.drawColor(defaultColor)
    view.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}
```

### **`Example`**

```
//@param rootView is View object which you want to get bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(rootView);
Bitmap bitmapColored = getBitmapFromView(rootView,Color.WHITE);
```

### **`PixelCopy Api`**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52985554/9909365

```
fun getBitmapFromView(view: View, activity: Activity, callback: (Bitmap) -> Unit) {
    activity.window?.let { window ->
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val locationOfViewInWindow = IntArray(2)
        view.getLocationInWindow(locationOfViewInWindow)
        try {
            PixelCopy.request(window, Rect(locationOfViewInWindow[0], locationOfViewInWindow[1], locationOfViewInWindow[0] + view.width, locationOfViewInWindow[1] + view.height), bitmap, { copyResult ->
                if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                    callback(bitmap)
                }
                // possible to handle other result codes ...
            }, Handler())
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            // PixelCopy may throw IllegalArgumentException, make sure to handle it
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

For More See About

[Bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap)

[Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas)

Comment: how can I get portion of view. createBitmap seems to take only width and height, looking for x,y,width,height

Comment: @Alex user this `Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)`

Comment: and how do you get source now. Bcz view.getDrawingCache() is deprecated which was returning bitmap.

Comment: @Alex first use this method to get bitmap of view the modify as u need

Comment: kotlin has a View.drawToBitmap extension function, which takes scrollX/Y into consideration

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    private fun convertViewToDrawable(view: View): Bitmap {
    val spec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    view.measure(spec, spec)
    view.layout(0, 0, view.measuredWidth, view.measuredHeight)
    val b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.measuredWidth, view.measuredHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val c = Canvas(b)
    c.translate((-view.scrollX).toFloat(), (-view.scrollY).toFloat())
    view.draw(c)
    return b
}
```

Comment: What's the need of translate, and of scrolling values?

Comment: Without it, if the view is scrolled, the part of the view that gets written to the bitmap will not match the part of the view that is actually visible.

Answer (score 2):

As of the official documentation [getDrawingCache()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache()) you should use the [PixelCopy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy) api.

Comment: Do I need to use SurfaceView to use PixelCopy(). Cause in android documentation it sayes "pixel copy requests to allow for copy operations from Surface to Bitmap".

Comment: add an example of pixelCopy() to capture bitmap of view

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki please checkout my answer. It works on.

Comment: how to use: https://medium.com/@hiteshkrsahu/a-complete-guide-for-taking-screenshot-in-android-28-bcb9a19a2b6e

Comment: The use of PixelCopy is not necessarily "should". The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache()) only recommends using it for UI feedback report and unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

much precise code..

```
private fun convertViewToDrawable(view: View): Bitmap {
        val b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.measuredWidth, view.measuredHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val c = Canvas(b)
        c.translate((-view.scrollX).toFloat(), (-view.scrollY).toFloat())
        view.draw(c)
        return b
    }
```

Comment: Why the need of translate, and of scrolling values?

Answer (score 0):

Some other kotlin code (ScrollView case)

```
val ScrollView.bitmap: Bitmap
get() {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, getChildAt(0).height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    with(Canvas(bitmap)) {
        val background = background
        if (background != null) {
            background.draw(this)
        } else {
            drawColor(Color.WHITE)
        }
        draw(this)
    }
    return bitmap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bitmap = view.drawToBitmap()
val pixel = bitmap.getpixel(x,y)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin code with view inflation:

```
fun getBitmapFromView(layoutInflater: LayoutInflater): Bitmap =
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutID, null).run {
    //Bind data If you needed Example - [findViewById<TextView>(R.id.viewId).text = data]
    measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    layout(0, 0, measuredWidth, measuredHeight)
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(measuredWidth, measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    draw(canvas)
    bitmap
}
```

layoutInflater can be retrieved like,

1. Inside activity or fragment -
   this.layoutInflater
2. Outside activity or fragment -
   val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater