# Video section not captured while taking screenshot

Tags: android, html5-video, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

I am working on a project where I wanted to take screenshots of the current window (inside the application only).

My application consist of a webview, and I am loading webpages on that. webpage contains videos, images...
If the webpage plays the video and I try to take the screenshot it shows as black color in the video player position.

### Method to take screenshot ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15638343/2769892))

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
   View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
   rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}

 public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Used libraries

- [Screenshott](https://github.com/nisrulz/screenshott)
- [hiddenshot](https://github.com/karanvs/hiddenshot)
- [InstaCapture](https://github.com/tarek360/InstaCapture)

None of the above are worked.
Here is a sample screenshot taken by the device[image]

Please let me know if there is any way to fix this issue.

Comment: Possibly related/useful: [view.getDrawingCache() is deprecated in Android API 28](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52642055/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang I have tried in older APIs and same issue happens

Comment: hope this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513379/how-to-record-screen-and-take-screenshots-using-android-api.