# How to use PixelCopy API in android java to get bitmap from View

Tags: java, android

Currently I am using **view.getDrawingCache()** now get drawing cache is **deprecated**

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitamp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache())
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

[view.getDrawingCache() is deprecated in Android API 28](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52642055/4088209)

Solution in java code is have getting error `Callback`

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public static void getBitmapFormView(View view, Activity activity, Callback callback) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        int[] locations = new int[2];
        view.getLocationInWindow(locations);
        Rect rect = new Rect(locations[0], locations[1], locations[0] + view.getWidth(), locations[1] + view.getHeight());

        PixelCopy.request(activity.getWindow(), rect, bitmap, copyResult -> {
            if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                callback.onResult(bitmap);
            }
        }, new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));
    }
```

Can not resolve **Callback**

- Activity
- Window
- Handler

which is supper class of callback ?

Comment: callback is interface inside PixelCopy.java Listener for observing the complation of a PixelCopy request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this article CallBack interface is `OnPixelCopyFinishedListener` is available in PixalCopy.java file

```
/**
 * Listener for observing the completion of a PixelCopy request.
 */
public interface OnPixelCopyFinishedListener {
    /**
     * Callback for when a pixel copy request has completed. This will be called
     * regardless of whether the copy succeeded or failed.
     *
     * @param copyResult Contains the resulting status of the copy request.
     * This will either be {@link PixelCopy#SUCCESS} or one of the
     * <code>PixelCopy.ERROR_*</code> values.
     */
    void onPixelCopyFinished(@CopyResultStatus int copyResult);
}
```

https://medium.com/@shiveshmehta09/taking-screenshot-programmatically-using-pixelcopy-api-83c84643b02a

Android docs for PixelCopy [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy)

Comment: Thank you save my time to creating bitmap -@Mansukh Ahir