Layout Not Being Drawn to PDF Properly in Android
I'm using the following code to create a document and write to a file. However, when I view the created pdf file, all the views have been drawn except for images. I tried to set the layout as the content of an activity to find out if my images were corrupted, or I had to resize them, but they render flawlessly when running the app. What might be the problem in this case? Do I need to write images programmatically?
Here's the code:
 val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.pdf, null)

        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            context.display?.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics)

        } else {
            context.windowManager.defaultDisplay?.getMetrics(displayMetrics)

        }
        view.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(displayMetrics.widthPixels, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(displayMetrics.heightPixels, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY))

        view.layout(0,0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels)

        val document = PdfDocument()
        val width = view.measuredWidth
        val height = view.measuredHeight

        val pageInfo = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(width, height, 1).create()
        val page = document.startPage(pageInfo)

        val canvas = page.canvas
        val bitMap = loadBitmapFromView(width, height)

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitMap, 0f,0f, null)
        view.draw(canvas)
        document.finishPage(page)
        document.writeTo(outputStream)
        document.close()
    }

    private fun loadBitmapFromView(width: Int, height: Int): Bitmap {
        val b: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        return b
    }


From memory there are some views like imageView and another popular one like Picasso that only support hardware rendering (drawing handled directly by the GPU). When you draw to a bitmap you are using software rendering. You might have to go with the pixel copy method to generate the bitmap to put in the PDF e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65828719/how-to-use-pixelcopy-api-in-android-java-to-get-bitmap-from-view

@Andrew but is there a way to copy a specific layout content rather than the current window itself?

@Andrew I think I could solve the problem by setting the image at runtime once again simply by using the .setImageResource() method. Thanks for your help!
