# How to get bitmap of view without losing the quality?

Tags: android, bitmap

As the `view.getDrawingCache()` is deprecated, I found the article below.

[view.getDrawingCache() is deprecated in Android API 28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642055/view-getdrawingcache-is-deprecated-in-android-api-28)

However, both `getDrawingCache` and the above way are of much lower quality than the original. Is there any way to make a bitmap without losing the quality?

please help me..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642055/view-getdrawingcache-is-deprecated-in-android-api-28

Comment: @Adnan I already refered that link ..