# Android : How to get scrollview full height?

Tags: android, scrollview

How do I find total Y or height of that scrollview? In that scrollview there a simple TextView with a Long text .

Here is my code:

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/White" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/scroll_text"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </ScrollView>
```

What i tried:

```
Log.e("ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN", scrollData.FOCUS_DOWN + ""); ---> Return 120
Log.e("scrollData.getBottom()", scrollData.getBottom() + "");---> Return 0
Log.e("scrollData", scrollData.getMeasuredHeight() + "");---> Return 0
```

Comment: Use **getMeasuredHeightAndState()** function to get height.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609297/android-total-height-of-scrollview or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054567/android-why-is-there-no-maxheight-for-a-view/13811461#13811461

Answer (score 2):

You can get the height of your `ScrollView` by measuring its child's height. You can get it done by using `ViewTreeObserver`

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObs = view.getViewTreeObserver(); 
viewTreeObs.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        this.view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        int width  = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

    } 
});
```