# How to get the scrollview total height = Scrollview.getScrollY() on Android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have already look on some forums but the tricks do not work for me.

I have this code:

```
scrollview = (ScrollView)v.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    scrollview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {

            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "scroll ch: "+scrollview.getScrollY()+"/"+scrollview.getChildAt(0).getHeight());
        }
    });
```

In my layout.xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/principal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@drawable/horiz"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="end|middle" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When I scroll down to the last I get the getScrollY() smaller than getChildAt(0).getHeight().

How can I get both having the same total size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe change

```
layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: I do what u wrote. Now I have both layout_height="match_parent". But it does not work. I got **scroll ch: 992/1758** from the log.

Comment: I get it now. 1758-992 = 766 = scrollview.getHeight(). so I did scrollview.getScrollY()+scrollview.getHeight() = scrollview.getChildAt(0).getBottom().

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 8):

Just to formally answer this, since I ran into the same issue.

If you log: `scrollView.getScrollY();` and scroll down to the bottom of your view you'll get a number that represents the height of your ScrollView. You'll notice that `scrollView.getHeight()` only gives you the height of the currently visible view. So you want to use: `scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609297/android-total-height-of-scrollview?rq=1). But that gives you a number greater than the maximum value of `scrollView.getScrollY()`. So you need to subtract it by the height of the scrollView.

TLDR:

```
totalHeightOfScrollView = scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight() 
    - scrollView.getHeight();
```

This will equal `scrollView.getScrollY()` at the bottom-most point.

Comment: Ok. but a better way to know if the Listview has reached the latest view or his end, you can try `listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "total now:"+(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount)+"/"+totalItemCount);
            }
        });`

Comment: I believe that's a different question, perhaps that was your originally intended question, but I was just outlining your own answer (in the form of a comment) to your original question.