# How to calculate the height of a scrollView using ViewTreeObserver?

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview

I have a ScrollView with some layouts in it, called the `fragment_about_sl.xml`.And the class associated to it is called `AboutSLFragment.java`.I want to calculate the height of the scrollView to get height ratio for an image.I researched the web and found this code.

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = scrollView.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
@Override 
public void onGlobalLayout() { 
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

int scrollViewHeightInPixels = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

//This is equal with %45 weight you tried before
int height = (scrollViewHeightInPixels * 45) / 100;
ViewGroup.LayoutParams pagerParams = viewPager.getLayoutParams();
pagerParams.height = height;
} 
});
```

As shown in the above code.It just have said `scrollView` instead of getting it from `findViewById()`.And also in the below code,it just says `layout.getMeasuredHeight()` instead of specifying the name of layout.

```
int scrollViewHeightInPixels = layout.getMeasuredHeight();
```

**The question is that I want to know what is meant by layout here(above).What should I put there,is it the id of the scrollView?If so I developed a code myself and I want to know whether it is correct.Please help me I am new to android.The id of the scrollview I used is aboutslscrollview.**

```
final View view = rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutslscrollview);
ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        int scrollViewHeightInPixels = view.getMeasuredHeight();

        //This is equal with %45 weight you tried before
        int height = (scrollViewHeightInPixels * 45) / 100;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams pagerParams = viewPager.getLayoutParams();
        pagerParams.height = height;
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Total height of ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609297/android-total-height-of-scrollview)

Comment: From which site you find that code?

Comment: In this line `view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);` this view is scrollView in above code change that first.

Comment: Hello Vishva, do you mean like this, rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutslscrollview).getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

Comment: also Vishva in this line of code, int scrollViewHeightInPixels = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); what is meant by layout, what should i put here, is it the id of the scrollView as well